# using results of stored procedure in a update query

Tags: sql-server-2005

how can i use result of stored procedure in update query?

Comment: i hav used result of stored procesure in insert query... but in update query i dont know how to use>..

Comment: -1 for multiple question marks. unclear problem definition. no code posted that was tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to insert the values from the Stored Procedure into a temp/variable table first, and then use it in an UPDATE statement.

Have a look at [Insert Values of Stored Procedure in Table](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/23/sql-server-insert-values-of-stored-procedure-in-table-use-table-valued-function/)

Comment: i have done that... but its taking too much time.... is there any method to do it by single query

Comment: No, there is no way of doing what you want.